# Need to get nearest map markers using zipcode in angular 5

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to be able to find the nearest map markers based on zipcode using Angular 5. The Google map markers are from a database I created. I know I can convert a zipcode into latitude and longitude using the Google Geocode Api but I don't know where to go from there.

Is there an Angular library that can calculate distances between Google map markers and a given latitude and longitude? I'm looking to create something similar to a store locator search, I'm just not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the method to calculate the distance between 2 marker

```
var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(marker, zipcode);
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry?hl=fr#Distance

Comment: Would I need to loop through all of my markers in your provided function to find the nearest markers based on a specific distance?